# Docker to limit cpu usage for any number of cpus

Tags: linux, docker, cpu, limit, cgroups

I need to run docker container on different VMs with 80% cpu processing time limit. At the same time I don't know how many cpu/cores/threads target VM will have. Docker offers a few arguments to [control cpu limits](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler). The most suitalbe for me - `cpu-quota`. But looks like it's per cpu. For instance I have VM with the following configuration:

```
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
```

When I set `cpu-quota` to 80000 (which is 80% of 10K) then it uses just one cpu, not 2 available cpus.

Is there nay way to put 80% cpu limit in a common way to not adjust it for each VM? Literally I need to say "hey, regardless of how many cpus/cores/threads etc you have, pls let this container to use only 80%"? Is it possible? If no, what would be the way to go, put limit for each VMs individually?

Answer (score 2):

as the website say: [control cpu limits](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler)

--cpu-period means

> Specify the CPU CFS scheduler period

--cpu-quota means

> Impose a CPU CFS quota on the container. The number of microseconds per --cpu-period that the container is limited to before throttled

if you use `--cpu-quota` you must use `--cpu-period` first

`--cpus` is a more convenient alternative

`--cpus 1.6`

This is the equivalent of setting `--cpu-period="100000" and --cpu-quota="160000"`

if you want use all 2 cpus, which uses 80%:

you can use the setting: `--cpu-period="80000" and --cpu-quota="200000"`

if you want to run same command in every VMs:

`--cpu-period="80000" --cpu-quota="$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l)0000"`

Comment: I didn't get this one `--cpu-period="80000" and --cpu-quota="200000"` could pls elaborate a bit more? Why quote > period? Am I right that I have to set period & quote per each VM? There is no way to set it just once?

Comment: yes, I have to set period & quote per each VM. you can use shell to get the cpu's count aotument, which above the upated answer

Comment: Why quote > period?  the document says it....

Comment: yeah did so. I use ansible so it was pretty easy